# NSString characterSetWithCharactersInString returns empty strings

Tags: ios, csv, nsstring, substring

I'm trying to break a `NSString` into the comma separated components. Somehow my `NSString` containing 25000 components always returns 25.500 values, 500 of which are empty `NSStrings`.  Here's what my code looks like:

```
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:nil];
/* do stuff */
NSMutableArray* components = 
 [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
   [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
     [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",\n\r "]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
[@"\n,\n"componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",\n\r "]];
```

The result shows how `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` behaves. Four components, all empty strings. Do you see why?

I'm not quite sure what you were expecting it to do, but that is what it does do. It just splits at any of the characters you list. If two of them are next to each other, you get an empty string. Plus a string for before the first one and a string for after the last one.

So the reason you are getting 25500 components is that, given the command you gave, that is how many components there *are*.